# How do I document a type alias defined using `type` in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting, docstring, type-alias, python-3.12

Python 3.12 has the [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#type) statement. How do I document the type alias properly?

I tried:

```
type Number = int | float
"""Represents a scalar number that is either an integer or float"""
```

But this doesn't seem to associate the docstring with the alias. I tried putting the docstring after the `=` and before the alias definition, but that generated an error.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by _"But this doesn't seem to associate the docstring with the alias"_? Are you expecting the string to be added as a attribute somewhere, or are you using some static analysis tool (e.g. Sphinx, IDE hinting, etc.)?

Comment: I think that question is more for Python to answer than me. I just want to know the way to properly document a type alias.

If I add a docstring to a function the normal way, say def `test():\n"""This is a test"""`, one can access it via `test.__doc__`. I have to assume that this is what the Python tooling uses to grab the docstrings. I want to know how to do that for type aliases defined using the `type` keyword.

Comment: I found someone else asking this same question. https://discuss.python.org/t/docstrings-for-new-type-aliases-as-defined-in-pep-695/39816 It appears that this just isn't currently possible and this was a poor oversight when adding the `type` statement.